# ember action 'Nothing handled the action' within block component

Tags: ember.js

If I have component in block form:

```
//some-component.hbs
{{#some-component}}
    <button {{action "someAction"}}>test</button>
     <!-- assume you have multiple buttons here with multiple actions -->
{{/some-component}}

//some-component.js
Ember.Component.extend({
    actions: {
        someAction() {
            alert('NOT BEING CALLED');
        }
    }
});
```

using Ember > v2.0. The action is not being called.
If I call it:

```
{{some-component}}
```

and put:

```
<button {{action "someAction"}}>test</button>
```

inside the some-component.hbs template. then it works. but this way has some drawbacks which I want to avoid.

I've looked at the docs and everywhere it doesn't seem to have this sort of case.

Answer (score 1):

the answer is:

```
{{yield this}}
```

in the template

and:

```
{{#some-component as |component|}}
    <button {{action "someAction" target=component}}>TEST</button>
{{/some-component}}
```